# Is Visual Studio Community Edition Slow or Am I doing something wrong?

Tags: visual-studio, performance

I've been developing applications using Visual Studio for over a decade now. VS 2019 has been so slow to use, it's nearly impossible to get any work done with it. It's not just building, debugging or any intensive task, but the entire IDE in general.

The response from clicking on controls is slow. Moving, renaming or deleting a folder in a solution can cause the IDE to grind to a standstill while it figures out what to do, even if the folder is small. Cursor transitions from the editor pane of a window, for instance, to the menu or toolbar, doesn't change from an I-beam back to a default cursor. Moving or resizing a window sends the entire to a crawl often leaving update artifacts left on the screen

If there's no solution, I would like to at least know the cause of it. While NopCommerce project I work with has several projects, I went through the effort of unloading all the unneeded projects and it helped, but only a little. It's at the point where I now do most of my development on a MacBook Pro 2014 with 8GB running VSCode. My primary development box, a Windows box with 32GB of RAM, has become too slow to be usable.

Comment: Is there a small parallelogram icon somewhere near the lower left of your IDE frame? If so, this should show any 'background tasks' running. I think `Ctrl+E, Ctrl+T` will also show any such running tasks. If there's a lot, you will at least have some indication. I had lots for a while but disable something like "look for online solutions" or some such.